# how to insert array without key to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have array

```
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => melinda
)
```

And have database table

---

### |id|name|

How I can insert the name into my database using php?

I can do using looping on mysql_query, but it not good for my resource.

the code I made now is

```
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO badwords (word) VALUES('".$row."')");
    }
```

it work but I think there is another simple way.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a batch insert instead of looping if you'd like.

```
"INSERT INTO badwords (word) VALUES ('".implode( "'),('", $data)."')";
```

Not tested, But this should produce something like

```
"INSERT INTO badwords (word) VALUES ('john'),('melinda')
```

Comment: could be... but the way he's using data in his code i assume the name of the initial array is $data

Comment: this can lead to sql injection

Comment: @ llya Bursov it depends where the data is coming from, but that wasn't the question was it?

Comment: you're right, this is why I wrote - can, not will )

Answer (score 2):

you can try batch insert:

```
$queryValues = '';
foreach ($data as $row)
    $queryValues .= (($queryValues!='')?',':'').'(\''.mysql_escape_string($row).'\')';
if ($queryValues)
    mysql_query('INSERT INTO badwords (word) VALUES' . $queryValues);
```

NOTE: do not use mysql, use mysqli or pdo extensions